# Using jQuery to assign an active class to an area tag (image map)

Tags: jquery, image

Is there a way, through jQuery, to assign an active class to an area tag within an a map?

I have a bunch of areas defined like this:

```
<map name="mappy"> 
    <area shape="rect" coords="162,105,179,136" href="#" title="Unique Title 1" alt="Unique Title 1" /> 
    <area shape="rect" coords="205,72,222,101" href="#" title="Unique Title 2" alt="Unique Title 2" /> 
</map>
```

What I need to figure out is if it is possible to add a some jQuery that sniffs out the title or alt tag and applies an active class to the area if there is a match.

Something like... `if title="Unique Title 1" then add class="active"` to area.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to find it and [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) to do the actual adding, like this:

```
$("area[title='Unique Title 1']").addClass("active");
```

Comment: Nick, i think you are addicted to SO

Comment: Works like a charm, but creates another problem with what i'm trying to do... isn't that always the way it goes.  Thanks!

Comment: @mkoryak - I answer questions mostly in a specific set of tags during the day, just depends how much you run across questions I answer/ask :)

Comment: I have the image map located in a hidden div that is accessed through a tab click.  The active tooltip appears when the page is loaded and renders in the upper corner of the content area (when it should still be hidden). I think I can solve this by putting this in my tab function rather than in the ready function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I completely understand what your asking for, but this may do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("map.mappy area").click(function() {
        $("map.mappy area").removeClass("active");  //Make sure no other "active" classes exist
        $(this).addClass("active");  //Add the active class to the area that was clicked
    });
});
```

Hopefully you wanted to add the active class in a click event, if not, I'm sure this could be modified easily to fit your needs (hover or whatever event your looking for).